# How to implement a Java equivalent of Rust's From trait?

Tags: java, interface, functional-programming

Rust has a convenient method to facilitate conversion between different types: the trait [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) (and [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html)) which defines an "interface" to convert an element to an other.

```rust
pub trait From<T> {
    fn from(T) -> Self;
}
```

Is it possible to implement an equivalent of the `From` trait with Java functional interfaces?

Comment: Java interfaces don't have an equivalent to Rust's `Self` type, so any implementation of this type of concept in Java would be unlikely to be anywhere near as useful.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need this method for?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have an equivalent for Rust’s extension traits. However, it is possible to implement an equivalent of the From trait with Java functional interfaces. You can use a functional interface with a single abstract method (SAM) as a replacement for Rust’s From trait2

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).